# Wordpress: exclude category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to exclude a category from my homepage, but my code didn't work:

```
<?php if( $category_items_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <div class="row columns-layout content-grid">
    <?php if( $layout === 'two' ): ?>

        <!-- EXCLUDE CATEGORY 17 -->
        <?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-17'); ?>

        <?php while( $category_items_query->have_posts() ): $category_items_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 recent-item two-columns post-box">
                <?php get_template_part( 'parts/home-content', 'columns' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .two-columns -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .row -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Please help me.
Thanks
Guido

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use query_posts as it is ineffiecnt and re-run sql queries and will also mess up your pagination..

Instead use pre_get_posts e.g.

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-17' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must define global variable like below , then you can try your code.

```
     global $query_string;
     query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-17');
```

Also there is another way that you can try as well : 
In function.php :

```
    function exclude_category( $wp_query ) {
       $excluded = array( '-1' );
       $wp_query->set('category__not_in', $excluded);
       set_query_var( 'category__not_in', $excluded );
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'demo_exclude_category' );
```

In your code (you can use in your way) :

```
class Exclude_Cat_Plugin {

public function __construct() {
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this,'exclude_first_category_posts') );
}

public function exclude_first_category_posts( $wp_query ) {

        if ( ! is_search() && ! is_archive() ) {
            $excluded = array( '-1' );
            $wp_query->set( 'category__not_in', $excluded );
            set_query_var( 'category__not_in', $excluded );
        }

  }

}
```

I hope its help you.